# Java regex : What is the best way to filter out the keyboard characters?

Tags: java, regex

Here is my regex that I am using to  remove all non keyboard characters from a string, i.e. leave all regular characters that could be typed in using a regular keboard :

```
String test = "\u2665\n\t\r whatever"; 
String myregex = "[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}\\,\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\|\"\' `~!@#$%^&*()_+-=,./<>?\n\r\t]+"; 
System.out.println(test.replaceAll(myregex, ""));
```

Is there a better way to do that ? Is there any more compact regex, more efficient regex ? 
        I am asking because initially I did not have this part of the regex `\n\r\t` and then realized that a user may hit `Enter` so that part was missing it . Maybe there is something else missing there ?

---

Basically what I am asking is : instead of listing all numbers and letters , we can use this  `\\p{L}\\p{Nd}` . Is there any other shortcut for the keyboard characters like `!@#$%  . .` ?

Comment: Yes. String may contain new lines, when a user hits `Enter`

Comment: I am not sure about `printable` . For example this one `\u2665` is a `heart character` . It is printable but it's not on a keyboard, so I don't want it

Comment: Why Unicode properties instead of `a-z0-9` ?

Comment: I guess I don't have a good answer to that :) I was just looking for a shortcut way . But it is not actually shorter .

Comment: So you want to keep all keyboard characters including newline, carriage return and tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can modify your regular expression as follows. This will remove any character(s) that are not from <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to <kbd>TILDE</kbd> in the **[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)** table and the exception of (`CR`, `LF` and `TAB`).

```
String myregex = "[^ -~\r\n\t]+";
```

Comment: Thank You ! I knew there was a better way